# Returning Aggregates Per Item in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a collection of documents (eg with fields for each student) and would like to return the aggregates for each student together in 1 query. I can only think of querying by student and then doing an aggregate but would like to prevent looping in my code to get the aggregate for each student.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly of your question, student name or student ID is part of the field in  your document?

For example,

```
{
  "name": "Steve",
  "id": "sid",
  "grade": 1,
  ...
}
```

If this is the case, I think you would just need to do a nested aggregation. Put terms aggregation based on student's `name` or `id` field first, and then do nested aggregation under the terms aggregation for field of your interests.

Reference:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html
- https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-aggregations-nested-documents-tutorial